# Change SelectedIndex of multiple ComboBoxes from a string of values in order

Tags: .net, vb.net

**Context**:
I have 20 `ComboBoxes` in a `GroupBox` with values `0-9` inside of each. I also have a string 20 digits long that hold values `0-9`. Example:

> 02023000230002300023

**Question**:
How can I pick the `SelectedIndex` of each `ComboBox`in the `GroupBox` by reading the string in order one digit at a time?

So lets say, 
 
the first value in the string is `0`, I want to select index `0` for `ComboBox1`, the second value in the string is `2`, I want to select index `2` for `ComboBox2` and so on using some kind of loop.

I don't want to write each line out manually for this process because I might have many more `ComboBoxes` in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no official promise that the order of the controls in the `ControlCollection` will reflect the Designer order, you could order those Controls by `Name` or by `TabIndex`, pick the one that best suits your scenario.

Here, ordered by `Name`:

```
Dim Indexes As String = "02023000230002300023"

Dim ListOfValues As New List(Of String)
For Each cb As ComboBox In (GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)().
                            OrderBy(Function(cbx) cbx.Name.Length).
                            ThenBy(Function(cbx) cbx.Name).ToList())

    cb.SelectedIndex = Integer.Parse(indexes(ListOfValues.Count))
    ListOfValues.Add(cb.GetItemText(cb.Items(Integer.Parse(indexes(ListOfValues.Count)))))

Next
```

On exit, `ListOfValues` will have all the extracted values from all the `ComboBoxes` at the index specified by the corresponding numeric value in the `Indexes` string.

***An explanation of what those three lines of code are doing***:
The `For Each` loop selects its values from the list of Controls of type `ComboBox` in the `GroupBox1` collection, then orders this list first by the lenght of the Name (`ComboBox.Name`), then by String Value. This allows to order the strings using their numeric part:
 (`1, 2, 3, (...), 10, 11, (...) 20` and not the usual `1, 11, 12, (...), 2, 20, 3 (...)`)

The inner loop line gets the numeric value of the `Indexes` string `Integer.Parse(indexes...)` using the current `Count` of the `ListOfValues` as the index of the value in the string (which is an array of chars).
`ComboBox.GetItemText()` retrieves the value of the current `ComboBox.Items` list at the position pointed by the extracted Index.

Finally, show the selected value in each `ComboBox`:
`cb.SelectedIndex = Integer.Parse(indexes(ListOfValues.Count))`

If a list of the selected values is not really needed, use an `Integer` variable, as shown in `Ctznkane525` answer.

To use the `ComboBox.TabIndex` as the comparer for the ordering, use this line instead:

```
GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)().OrderBy(Function(cbx) cbx.TabIndex).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot when I get these comboboxes in order

Comment: @Dan  You don't need to. This code is doing it for you :)

Comment: I understand it orders them in code. I actually have many more than 20 comboboxes, don't ask why.. So I have multiple columns on CBs and when I copy pasted them in it would go from 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 5, etc. So when someone goes down the list and enters their values I want it to be in the right order for saving and loading. Not sure if that made sense.

Comment: @Dan  I won't ask you why :) I meant, that code can be used to order the `ComboBoxes` by Name, the main method used as of now, but, as shown below, also by `TabIndex`. I assume you will assign a `TabIndex` anyway, to let the users tab through those controls with ease. (Still not asking).

Comment: Well maybe I am taking the long route to my destination but that's ok haha.

Comment: Awesome! After ordering all of my comboboxes on the screen and pasting in the code and putting in my string that I create from the screen it looks like it is loading all the values into the comboboxes correctly! THANKS!

Comment: @Dan Well, I'm glad it worked out (nope, not asking).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Z order of your comboboxes matches your desired order, you can do this:

```
Dim stringValue as String = "02023000230002300023"
Dim counter as Integer = 0
For Each c As ComboBox In groupBox.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
    c.Text = stringValue.Substring(counter, 1)
    counter += 1
Next
```

If it doesn't give you the right order, then change the control order in your designer.

Reference:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks! I will try tomorrow. Can explain more about changing the control order? You mean just moving the comboboxes around so its in order from 1-20?

Comment: no...i dont...you can right click on them and "send to back" in reverse order...that i believe will take care of it...visual studio has a function also for z ordering...controlling what the first, second, third, etc controls are in order

Comment: You can use the Document Outline window to set the z-order explicitly at design time.

Comment: I would tend to put the controls in an array and use a `For` loop rather than a `For Each` loop and separate counter.